# Meeting of 8 flies

Tags: geometry, physics

In the following diagram 8 flies are located at the corners of a cubic room, 10 feet on each side. At time 0 each fly starts to fly towards its neighbor fly as indicated in the diagram. Their speed of flight is 5 feet/sec. Each fly continues to fly towards its neighbour, and corrects its flight direction as its neighbour fly moves.
Will their movement converge? Where? How long will it take for them to meet? Will they meet in the same time?

[image]

Comment: Does this mean they can start moving diagonally?

Comment: Yep. "They correct the flight direction" Otherwise it isn't an interesting problem.

Comment: They are not moving diagonally - see the arrows on the drawing.

Comment: The arrows denote the initial direction. They correct the direction as each fly moves.

Comment: How could possibly two objects moving on parallel lines ever converge? Like the question "where will the parallel lines cross?". Or am I interpreting the question incorrectly?

Comment: The movement could be of a spiral nature - as in the planar case of the famous 4 flies at the corners of a square.

Comment: If you want a visual, check my simulated solution.

Comment: Do you have a simple way to determine the time? The approach used for the 2D case does not work here because the angles do not remain the same.

Comment: Yes there is a simple way to determine the time. And why you claim the angel does not remain the same? See the simulation by Alexis.

Comment: As soon as they start moving, angle BCD starts increasing above 90 degrees. In the 2D case,the rotation of BC and CD would cancel out and keep the angle constant, but because BC and CD are rotating in different planes here, it does not cancel.

Comment: If your intended answer is to use the same argument as in the 2D case and assume that the angles do not change, you are wrong and your question is faulty.

Comment: @f" I think that you are grossly wrong - the simulation clearly helps in understanding it (Alexis removed it...) - the cube structure is maintained all the way to the middle, which means that the relative move and direction of the start are maintained.

Comment: The derivative of the measure of angle BCD at the starting moment is $\frac12$ radian per second. It is not zero and the angle is not constant.

Comment: What simulation are you talking about? There is no simulation in the answer below showing a cube shape being maintained and there is no edit history to show it being "removed". In fact, the answer contradicts you because the time would be exactly two seconds if you were correct, not "a little under four seconds".

Comment: Probably with flies flying starting from corners ABCFEH (and following each other in this order) the 2D-argument would still work.

Comment: I agree with @f'' that the cube shape is not maintained. A, B, and C initially move within the plane ABCD, but D moves directly out of it. A short time after the start, flies A,B,C, and D no longer lie in the same plane. You can see that in the Alexis Olson's picture. Symmetry arguments do show that A, C, E, G move in the same way, as so B, D, F, and H, but those two tetrahedra do not maintain their relative orientations.

Comment: It is clear that the angles are changing, but not at all trivial what does this change in the explanation. To be honest - though having a math degree - I still cannot see why does this lack of symmetry imply that their constant corrigation does not decrease the distance between the flies in a linear way. Is there an intuitive explanation for that, or only one with frightening differential equations?

Comment: The original problem relies on the fact that while fly A is moving toward fly B, that B continually moves in a direction perpendicular to A-B, so that the distance that A travels does not change by B's movement. If any of the angles becomes different to 90 degrees, the distance travelled and hence the time needed will change. In this case BCD becomes larger than 90, so C is moving partially away from B, and B will need more than 2 seconds to reach C (unless that angle somehow gets smaller later to compensate).

Comment: This seems like a mathbook-type problem to me, not a math *puzzle*.

Comment: @Mithrandir I second that.

Comment: Thanks, @JaapScherphuis, it is clear now, it was only my short-sightedness. In this case, Mithrandir is right, that this puzzle probably needs way too much math to solve.

Comment: THIS IS A PUZZLE - as the 4 fly challenge is a puzzle. All encryption problems here may be defined (almost all using off the shelf tools) as math problem well solved with existing tools.

Comment: @ elias, IAmInPLS, Jon Mark Perry, Beastly Gerbil, Aggie Kidd Don't you think that the community had a clear vote?

Comment: I looked there and it is clear to me that this is a puzzle, exactly like the 4 fly puzzle. Using math tools to get results does not make a puzzle an un-puzzle. Using the tools right with proper insight turns story to a puzzle... here there is a need to utilize a 3D view, realizing that the component toward the center is constant while there are variants on the plan perpendicular to this direction. Is this physics? Math? Insight? - THIS IS A PUZZLE. Not like the various encryption  games, but still requires some thought...

Comment: The original 4 fly puzzle has an Aha-moment, that does not apply to this one. If you had chosen the ABCFEH variant that elias mentions above, then it would be a puzzle equivalent to the 4 fly one. In your version the angles do not stay the same, and the component towards the cube centre does not remain the same (it becomes less I think). This makes it a maths research project, not a puzzle.

Comment: Well, allow me not to agree with you. Over 45 years of solving puzzles make a move from 2D to 3D as a Aha-moment. Like building 4 equilateral triangles with 6 matches when with 3 you could build only 1...

Answer (score 27):

Here's a simulated solution using *Mathematica*.

The flight paths will look like this:

> [image: Mathematica graph]

They will

> converge in a little under 4 seconds.

Here's the code for the image:

```
a[1] := {1, 1, 1}
b[1] := {0, 1, 1}
c[1] := {0, 0, 1}
d[1] := {1, 0, 1}
e[1] := {1, 0, 0}
f[1] := {0, 0, 0}
g[1] := {0, 1, 0}
h[1] := {1, 1, 0}

s := 0.001
n := 2/s
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, If[Norm[b[i] - a[i]] < s, Break[]];
 a[i + 1] = a[i] + s (b[i] - a[i])/Norm[b[i] - a[i]];
 b[i + 1] = b[i] + s (c[i] - b[i])/Norm[c[i] - b[i]];
 c[i + 1] = c[i] + s (d[i] - c[i])/Norm[d[i] - c[i]];
 d[i + 1] = d[i] + s (e[i] - d[i])/Norm[e[i] - d[i]];
 e[i + 1] = e[i] + s (f[i] - e[i])/Norm[f[i] - e[i]];
 f[i + 1] = f[i] + s (g[i] - f[i])/Norm[g[i] - f[i]];
 g[i + 1] = g[i] + s (h[i] - g[i])/Norm[h[i] - g[i]];
 h[i + 1] = h[i] + s (a[i] - h[i])/Norm[a[i] - h[i]];]

ListPointPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i], f[i], g[i], h[i]}, {i,1, n}], 1],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Small] , AspectRatio -> 1]
```

For the time I used a smaller `s` and counted the total number of steps times the length of each step

```
s := 0.00001
n := 2/s
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, If[Norm[b[i] - a[i]] < s, Break[]];
 a[i + 1] = a[i] + s (b[i] - a[i])/Norm[b[i] - a[i]];
 b[i + 1] = b[i] + s (c[i] - b[i])/Norm[c[i] - b[i]];
 c[i + 1] = c[i] + s (d[i] - c[i])/Norm[d[i] - c[i]];
 d[i + 1] = d[i] + s (e[i] - d[i])/Norm[e[i] - d[i]];
 e[i + 1] = e[i] + s (f[i] - e[i])/Norm[f[i] - e[i]];
 f[i + 1] = f[i] + s (g[i] - f[i])/Norm[g[i] - f[i]];
 g[i + 1] = g[i] + s (h[i] - g[i])/Norm[h[i] - g[i]];
 h[i + 1] = h[i] + s (a[i] - h[i])/Norm[a[i] - h[i]];]
(i - 1) s
```

which returns `1.96457`.

This is for a unit cube with unit velocity.
Double the time for the case where the cubes have sides of length 10 feet and the velocity is 5 feet / second.

**Additional images:**

Front:

> [image: Front]

Side:

> [image: Side]

Rotating:

> [image: Rotating]

Note that the flies do not

> maintain the cubic shape as they spiral inward. In fact, the angles between two adjacent fly trajectories follows one of the two paths shown in this graph
>  [image: Angles between trajectories]
>  where the y-axis is given in degrees.

For reference, here's a math paper on cyclic pursuits in more general cases:

[Ants, Crickets and Frogs in Cyclic Pursuit](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~alon/papers/frog.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the simulation but this is not an acceptable solution. IT IS NICE!!! and demonstrate that there is a point in seeking an explanation why under 4 second and is it really into one point at the center of the cube.

Comment: Yeah. Certainly not a proper solution, but rather a springboard to visualize the problem and get a general idea of what is going on. You should choose whoever can actually prove it.

Comment: @Alexis Can you please share the code also? I would really like to see it. :)

Comment: @KeithN Code is added in.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Wow... I would love to know where you learned that if you don't mind.

Comment: @Moti Why is this solution not acceptable? Isn't it right?? If you don't want the use of computers, add a no-computer tag.

Comment: @KeithN Lots of practice. I used Mathematica throughout undergrad and grad school in mathematics and I've solved over 100 [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problems using it too.

Comment: Could you please add a picture showing a different angle, more from the side of the spiral? I would very much like to see just how flat the spiral is. I think the flies almost end up in a plane (y=0.5), chasing each other around in a circle. A different viewpoint will show more clearly that they do not remain in a cube arrangement.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I've added a couple more views. They do converge towards a plane.

Comment: So where do they converge? (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) or elsewhere?

Comment: @smci Yes. At the center: $(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)$.

Comment: @ABcDexter, I think there's a useful distinction between two ways to use a computer to solve a puzzle. One is where the computer *gives you a proof*, and by copying what the computer says you have a complete answer. The other is where the computer *gives you an approximate answer* leaving you probably knowing the answer but  without actual proof that it's right. This is the second sort of case; to my mind the no-computer tag is more about the first.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, this sounds better. I've had similar experiences in answering.

Comment: @ABcDexter I think Gareth explains it well. You could define the set of solutions and than use a computer to test their accuracy. Simulation of the case is not the same. This is the old argument with regard to proofs by the use of computer. I think that Alexis did a GREAT service pointing to the direction. Does this is a proof that they meet at (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) - no. it get close to it as much as we want - MAY BE. Who guarantees that there is no a small circle around which they run, or two groups... Hope you see the distinction between a proof and a test.

Comment: @Moti Yes, I know the difference between a proof and test. I was just asking you to clarify the question.

Comment: Hope I clarified the point. I will be happy to accept the solution - very nice work/effort by Alexis - if someone can organize a voting on it and enough majority will claim it a solution - but it must include Alexis as claiming it a solution. It is on hold because some puzzle experts did not like it - claims it is a MATH problem...

Comment: What exactly distinguishes a puzzle from a math problem? I think convergence in finite time should be able to be proven using fairly basic arguments, but the exact time until convergence may be difficult.

Comment: I got an identical solution using `NDSolve` instead of Euler integration: `With[{coords={{1,1,1},{0,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{1,1,0}},funcs={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}},soln=NDSolve[Join[Thread[Through[funcs[0]]==coords],#1'[t]==Normalize[#2[t]-#1[t]]&@@@Partition[funcs,2,1,1],{WhenEvent[Norm[a[t]-b[t]]<1*^-9,{tstop=t,"StopIntegration"}]}],funcs,{t,0,2}];]` (plot with e.g. `ParametricPlot3D[Through[soln[[1, ;; , 2]][t]], {t, 0, tstop}]`)

Comment: @Alexis You are right and I am on the verge of accepting your solution...:) Need some "voting" of others... If only you would provide a slight insight why there is a convergence - the "instinctive" one... A simple drawing for the relation of two points?

Comment: @Moti I'll try to update with such an argument soon. Then perhaps we can edit the question a bit and maybe get it off hold. I'm thinking proving convergence within an explicit time bound should be doable and sufficient for an answer. Location and simultaneity of convergence seem like they'd require some kind of symmetry argument that isn't readily apparent to me.

Comment: The arrangement has 4-fold rotoreflection symmetry ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_rotation ) around the x=z=0.5 axis. So it has 180 degree rotational symmetry around that axis, and if you reflect through the y=0.5 plane you get the same pattern rotated 90 degrees around that axis. The only fixed point of those transformations is (0.5,0.5,0.5) so if they converge to a single point, that must be it.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I would appreciate your help. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1964027/360611